# Is there a way to programmatically get a connected app secret and id?

Tags: apex, callout, connected-apps

We use JWT to pull and push updates to our sandboxes however the issue is that when we refresh the sandboxes, we have to go through each connected app and update our database with the new secrets and ids. We have started to build a SandboxPostCopy framework and I am wondering if there is any way I could query the connected app details and then push these out to our database automatically.

Comment: I'm not sure that would be possible, one possible way would have been via the metadata api, however looking at the documentation it says (re consumerSecret) "When set, the value isn’t returned in Metadata API requests." see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_connectedapp.htm

Comment: so in theory I could create a new app and share that detail (as I just made it) is there any way I could make this from within apex or do I need to make an callout?

Comment: I don't think you could do it in Apex without a callout

Comment: Consumer key - yes, secret - no.